# JQUERY image upload issue

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var myUpload = $('#upload_link').upload({
               name: 'image',
               action: '<?=$image_handling_file?>',
               enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
               params: {upload:'Upload'},
               autoSubmit: true,
               onSubmit: function() {
                    $('#upload_status').html('').hide();
                    loadingmessage('Veuillez patienter...', 'show');
               },
               onComplete: function(response) {
                    loadingmessage('', 'hide');
                    response = unescape(response);
                    var response = response.split("|");
                    var responseType = response[0];
                    var responseMsg = response[1];
                    if(responseType=="success"){
                        var current_width = response[2];
                        var current_height = response[3];
                        //display message that the file has been uploaded
                        $('#upload_status').show().html('<p><h2>Veuillez redimensionner votre image ci-dessous, puis cliquez Sauvegarder</h2></p>');
                        //put the image in the appropriate div
                        $('#uploaded_image').html('<img src="images/news/'+responseMsg+'" id="thumbnail" alt="Create headline image" /><center><div style="width:<?php echo $thumb_width;?>px; height:<?php echo $thumb_height;?>px; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; background: #F4F4F4; border-radius: 10px; moz-border-radius: 10px; border:1px #e5e5e5 solid;"><div style="overflow:hidden; width:<?php echo $thumb_width;?>px; height:<?php echo $thumb_height;?>px;"><img src="images/news/'+responseMsg+'" id="thumbnail_preview" alt="Thumbnail Preview" /></div></div></center>')
                        //find the image inserted above, and allow it to be cropped
                        $('#uploaded_image').find('#thumbnail').imgAreaSelect({ aspectRatio: '1:<?php echo $thumb_height/$thumb_width;?>', onSelectChange: preview }); 
                        //display the hidden form
                        $('#thumbnail_form').show();
                        $('#upload_par').hide();
                    }else if(responseType=="error"){
                        $('#upload_status').show().html('<h1>Erreur</h1><p>'+responseMsg+'</p>');
                        $('#uploaded_image').html('');
                        $('#thumbnail_form').hide();
                    }else{
                        $('#upload_status').show().html('<h1>Erreur</h1><p>Veuillez réessayer</p>'+response);
                        $('#uploaded_image').html('');
                        $('#thumbnail_form').hide();
                    }
               }
            });
});


<div id="upload_par"><a id="upload_link" href="#"><button type="button" class="btn" style="display:block;">Choisir une image</button></a></div>
```

What is the problem with my JQUERY?

The Developer's tool on Chrome gives me these error details:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'upload'
>   (anonymous function) f.Callbacks.njquery.js:2
>
> f.Callbacks.o.fireWithjquery.js:2
>
> e.extend.readyjquery.js:2
>
> c.addEventListener.B

Comment: jquery doesn't have a .upload() call. That's probably provided by some plugin which you're lacking.

Comment: Are your scripts being loaded after jQuery? Does it work in other browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function like `.upload()` in jQuery, you might want to use `.submit()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, there is no jquery upload function...submit will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed as *bardiir* says, there's no such thing as `upload()` function. You could use something like [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html#comment-form), make it more reusable, the up loader in [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html#comment-form) is pretty simple and easy to custom. Hope it helps.

The final code just for the loader would be something like:

```
$('#imageform').bind('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // <-- important
            $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                target: '#preview',
                success: function() {
                $('#file').val($('#newimg').attr("src"));
                }               
            });
        }).submit();
```

And all the magic can be handled by the **ajaxSubmit** and a PHP file to make de upload.